# How do I use Shrinkwrap Modifer with more control?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

This is the bust part of a onepiece from another model. 
The character is also of a different model. 
As shown that the character's bust is flat. 
I am unable to simply wrap the entire bust unit on the character since the top edge of the bust part in the original model is left unwrap. 
[image: Upperview: Top edge does not wrap the original character's bust]

[image: Inner Sideview: Orange part is the upper bust of the original character]
What steps shall I take to wrap the bust part of the onepiece dress so that it fits the bust of new character while remaining the edges. 
Or, is it possible to wrap only a face while the other part deforms accordingly, so that I can add another face inside the bust unit that covers the original character's bust and make only that face to wrap the new character while remaining the structure of the bust piece.

Comment: See Shrinkwrap Modifier.  Consider practicing a few this modifier on simple shapes before complex shapes.

Comment: Using shrinkwrap modifier on the entire unit makes the top edge attach as well. I am trying to only wrap part of the bust unit while have the top edge remain unattached.

Comment: Here is a video tutorial for a small start.  You should seek out a more technical video by searching ....   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2NwJsXBA2A

Comment: Shrink wrap works with weight vertex groups.  See that as well.  I would spend an hour to see that concept.  Weight painting.

Comment: So does that mean I shall split the model into different vertex groups and apply the shrinkwrap modifier? I saw a different post before posting showing how to wrap a belt with different vertex groups through shrinkwrap modifier and lattice modifier, but I am quite lost on how should I split my mesh so that it accomplish my goal.

Comment: Suggestion.  Recreate the answer below as an example.  Then submit a new question about splitting the model.    The new question may disappear.  A new one will appear.

Comment: Searching and finding more info here at the famous video website or here at BSE will teach you about more settings of ShrinkWrap.

Comment: Many times people show models made from quads.  I am suprised I do not see more quads in you model.  Was your model imported?

Comment: Yeah it is imported. I got into blender just a few day ago because of an interest of modeling game character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shrink Wrap with Vertex Group Weights**

By using vertex groups modified in weight paint you can exert more control.

---

[image]

A the very flat square box begin as a cube Mesh. Subdivided as seen, High Vertex Density. I will call it a box. Left to Right parts of the image -->

- For simple models you can consider texture painting.  I tend to think you do not want this.
- On the left the box is showing weights in edit. Painting occurred in Weight Paint Mode.  You can see vertex group names.  A Mesh can have many vertex groups. All hidden vertices are zero weight.
- Next the box with NO modifiers
- Next the box with Shrink Wrap Modifier ..and vertex group specified ... Note the red weights allow the vertices to move the most. The top of the box is stable and does not move, this is the control weight paint efforts allow.  Lets call this [Context 1]
- Next the box with Shrink Wrap Modifier ... No Vertex group .. it collapses to where many faces are close to each other .. lack of control
- Next same as in [Context 1] but the inverse of the group has been selected.  Only the red paint area stays in it original place. Weight of Vertex X is now (1 - original weight)
- Consider adding a second or more Shrink Wrap modifier your waist area.

**Notes**

---

- A flexible fabric in daily life conforms to a body.  Stretch Fabric even more.
- A bullet proof vest and bomb squad disposal suit might conform very little.
- You must use your judgement.  Breaking a model in to flexible and inflexible parts should be considered one of your tools, along with others.
- Practice simple cases of Weight Paint and ShrinkWrap.  Improve the example you see here.
- Weight Paint mastery is an essential skill for Shrinkwrap.
- Once you have control over the vertex group weights you can make more informed decisions.
- Then see more advanced tutorials.
- This is just a quick highlight. This topic requires further research.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting. I was able to get the bust done the way I like. However, before posting this question I did shrinkwrap for waist as well. Although it did wrap in the way I want, the edge did not end up the way I want. Is there any easy method to fix that. (See image: http://i.imgur.com/9aoBalM.png) The left is the original character. The right is the dress that I shrinkwrap. The curve is deform due to shrinkwrapping. I would like to know if it is possible to smooth it somehow so that at least it looks like the original one on the left.

Comment: By the way, there is also gloves part of this onepiece which does not fit the new character's hands. If I would do shrinkwrap in this case, do I still weight paint it? Or, can I just subdivide the vertex and wrap it around each finger and the palm.

Comment: You can ask a new idea question from your mind, in a new BSE question on a web page. Make sure you include  high quality images and show ShrinkWrap modifier settings.  I suggest you see tutorial videos of 10 minutes or more.  Also elaborate weight painting may require reasonable knowledge of Mesh Hide Vertices.  I do not know very much about your model.  A new question will show your progress.

Remember that I was really focusing on general technique and not your particular model.  Do you feel you have more mastery over weight painting.  Is weight painting getting easier?

Comment: Okay. I will start a new post later if I still need it. Weight painting is still quite hard. Is gonna take some practice until I am good at it.

Comment: Paint, Paint, Paint!  Hide vertices for difficult busy mesh hands.  See tutorials for weight painting.  Perhaps a second ShrinkWrap Modifier for waistline. Get Sleep as well.