# is there an inverse function of the circle function (w --> Loop tools) to form a square form a circle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

To create a circle from an edge loop in edit mode, there is the function under the specials menu. Access by <kbd>W</kbd> > *Loop Tools* > *Circle*.

But is there a Function to do the opposite?

[image: Circle and square meshes]

By now, I pick a quarter of amount of the circle vertices, scale them to an axis by zero, and doing this for all four quarters of the circle. but this only works as long as the circle is aligned to the main axes and has a number of vertices that can be divided by four.

Comment: When you write  [is there a Function] .... do you mean any method that gets the visual result.  Please advise if this is not the case.  Also it is not clear if you have only a single curve or a mesh.  I realize you may have chosen to make the visuals clear.

Comment: Let [V] be the number of vertices in your question. The symbol | means divides evenly.  Yes your discussion of 4 | [V] makes sense.  You would need to explain if you have a particular requirement when it is not the case that 4 | [V]. If no particular requirement exists then you could just have somewhat equal distribution of the vertices.  A quick estimate is 3 cases.

Comment: Do you have a preference for a edit mode change or object mode change?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-can-i-morph-a-flat-plane-to-be-a-flat-cirlce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Cast modiifer > Cuboid, Factor: 1, and apply it if you want to. It doesn't distribute vertices evenly between the corners, though... and still only plays fair with a nice number of vertices ..

Comment: Hi Robin, this was a pretty usefull tip! as long as the number of verts can be divided by four, it works as expected. This is the fist time i use the cast modifier at all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pixelpoems.de Thanks! I hope you give atomicbezierslinger's answer a UV..The Shrinkwrap  option covers all the bases..

Answer (score 1):

**Two or more alternatives**

- shrink wrap modifier to conform one surface to another.
  You can start with a circle shape and shrinkwrap to a square.
- shape keys
- shape keys from a shrinkwrap
- Possibly a Python Script

[image]

Before and after using a shrinkwrap modifier with 9 vertices.  The number 4 does not evenly divide 9. Thus one edge has 1 more vertex than the others. Corners are placed with a shape key since corners are especially perceptible and defining.  Shrinkwrap and Shapekey shown. Image above.

You can also see

[How do I use Shrinkwrap Modifer with more control?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86888/how-do-i-use-shrinkwrap-modifer-with-more-control/86895#86895)

Please not this is not a tutorial on the topics.  It is a suggestion to use the modifiers and other tool to see if they can adequately address your situation.

Comment: I never knew Shrinkwrap would work without face normals.. I just assumed it wouldn't ! That is _so_ useful...

Comment: So many things about Blender to remember and forget.