# I want to animate the position of a single vertex

Tags: animation, vertices

I'm building a simple animation using only individual planes as  objects.  I want to animate the position of a single vertex on one of the planes.  The solutions I've found in the Blender manual so far have involved numerous complicated steps and seem to be explained by engineers in technical word salad.  Can anyone suggest a simple explanation for a simple solution?

Comment: look into Shape Keys, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229277/how-can-i-blend-two-objects-i-e-fillup-objects-between-two-different-objects/229279#229279

Comment: you can also hook your vertex to an empty or to a bone, it may be better than shape keys, it all depends on the kind of animation you need, please give some details

Comment: [technical word salad] is what you wrote.   It is always refreshing to hear some words of truth about the manual.  At some point in the future you may simply accept that state of affairs.

Comment: You may consider shrinkwrap.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86888/how-do-i-use-shrinkwrap-modifer-with-more-control/86895#86895   You stated you have only one single vertex today ... in the future you may have more than one.

Comment: @lindal you asked the same question again today after 10 months XD https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262553/i-want-to-animate-a-vertex-on-a-plane/262560#262560

Answer (score 7):

1. select your plane and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode

[image]

[image]

2. Select the vertex you want to animate

[image]

3. Press <kbd>CTRL-H</kbd> -> hook to new object

[image]

4. press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to object mode

[image]

5. Now you can move the newly created empty as you want and the vertex will move with it. Of course you can keyframe the movement of this empty too.

[image]