# I want to animate a vertex on a plane

Tags: animation, vertices

I want to animate a single vertex on a plane.  I do this a lot so it needs to be simple.

Comment: You can keyframe the ShapeKey or keyframe the vertice.

Comment: it looks like you already asked the same question 10 months ago but did not mark it as answered in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229343/i-want-to-animate-the-position-of-a-single-vertex. can you please mark it answered so we can close it :)

Answer (score 0):

Select a vertex in *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and click *Hook to New Object*. This creates a new *Empty* object. Go back to *Object Mode* and now you can move or animate this *Empty* object which effectively drags the hooked vertex along.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something because I can't get it to work with my plane and I can't get it to work with your box.

Comment: did you select one vertex? then what happens when you press CTRL+H ?

Comment: The last time I tried it the plane moved but the hook didn't.  Another time I tried it the whole plane went wonky.  I've tried several different times and each time it hasn't worked,  never with the same outcome.

Comment: I'm giving up for tonight.  I'll try it again tomorrow.

Comment: it looks like you need to reinstall blender coz this can't be this hard. install the latest blender 3.1 XD

Comment: Finally got it to work.  The problem seemed to be that the plane I was working on was parented to another plane.  Thanks for your help.